# How to set the background of a button to a random colour with set constraints?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have got a function which sets the background colour of all of my buttons to red, and it currently works like this, however, what i'd like to do is make this be set to a random colour with set constraints, with these being the maximum amount of random colours that can be picked from, as well as the maximum amount of the same colour assigned to each button.

For example, if the max amount of random colours is 8 and the max amount of the same colour is 2, only 8 random colours will be chosen, and the same colour will be allocated to exactly 2 buttons only.

This is for a matching pairs game that I am creating. I have already created a function which sets a random colour to all of the buttons when they are clicked, however, this does not have the constraints in place that I was talking about earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
    arrayButtons[i].setDrawColor(new Color(rand.nextInt()));
}
```

You need to create half the random colors and color 2 buttons with them, and then shuffle the array. I would use an ArrayList -- easier to shuffle and to add things to. So assuming a `List<ColorButton>` called buttonList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.size() / 2; i++) {
    Color color = new Color(rand.nextInt();
    buttonList.get(2 * i).setDrawColor(color));
    buttonList.get(2 * i + 1).setDrawColor(color));
}
Collections.shuffle(buttonList);
```

or if you must use arrays, and will shuffle the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length / 2; i++) {
    Color color = new Color(rand.nextInt();
    arrayButtons[2 * i].setDrawColor(color));
    arrayButtons[2 * i + 1].setDrawColor(color));
}
// shuffle your array here
```

---

Edit: I've changed my mind. Easiest to create a `List<Color>`, fill it with 8 pairs of distinct colors, shuffle it and then add the colors to the buttons. Rather than random colors, if you want all of them bright, use 8 distinct *hues* of colors using Color's `.getHSBColor(...)` method:

```
    List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        float hue = i * 1f / 8;
        Color c = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, 1f);
        colorList.add(c);
        colorList.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(colorList);
    // add colors to buttons in for loop
```

or...

```
colorList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS / 2; i++) {
    float r = (float) Math.random();
    float g = (float) Math.random();
    float b = (float) Math.random();
    Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
    colorList.add(color);
    colorList.add(color);
}
Collections.shuffle(colorList);

// add colors to buttons using for loop
```

Myself, I would do things a bit differently:

- I wouldn't extend JButton
- I'd separate my model out from my view using a variant of the model-view-controller program structure
- All the logic would be held in the model, including the random 8 number pairs randomly shuffled in an `ArrayList<Integer>`

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ColorTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROWS = 4;
    private static final int COLS = 4;
    private static final int BTN_W = 100;
    private static final int BTN_H = 100;
    private static final Dimension BTN_SIZE = new Dimension(100, 100);
    // how long to show mismatched color pairs
    private static final int COLOR_DISPLAY_DELAY = 2000; // msecs
    private static final int NO_PICK = -1;
    private List<ColorButton2> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int firstPick = NO_PICK;
    private int secondPick = NO_PICK;
    private ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    private boolean listenerEnabled = true;

    public ColorTest() {
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        for (int index = 0; index < ROWS * COLS; index++) {
            ColorButton2 button = new ColorButton2(index, BTN_W, BTN_H);
            button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
            button.setPreferredSize(BTN_SIZE);
            buttonList.add(button);
            gridPanel.add(button);
        }
        reset();

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(e -> reset());
        resetButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        exitButton.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        btnPanel.add(resetButton);
        btnPanel.add(exitButton);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridPanel);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void reset() {
        colorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS / 2; i++) {
            // Color color = randomRgbColor();
            float hue = (2f * i) / (ROWS * COLS); // non-random hue
            Color color = randomHsbColor(hue); // randomize the saturation and
                                               // brilliance
            colorList.add(color);
            colorList.add(color);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(colorList);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
            ColorButton2 btn = buttonList.get(i);
            btn.reset();
            btn.setColor(colorList.get(i));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Color randomRgbColor() {
        float r = (float) Math.random();
        float g = (float) Math.random();
        float b = (float) Math.random();
        Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
        return color;
    }

    private Color randomHsbColor(float hue) {
        // float hue = (float) Math.random();
        float sat = ((int) (2 * Math.random()) + 1) / 2f;
        float bril = ((int) (2 * Math.random()) + 1) / 2f;
        return Color.getHSBColor(hue, sat, bril);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!listenerEnabled) {
                // if button listener disabled -- get out of here
                return;
            }
            ColorButton2 source = (ColorButton2) e.getSource();
            if (source.getNumber() == firstPick) {
                // if user chooses same button twice, a mistake, so exit
                return;
            }
            if (source.isPairMatched()) {
                // button already matched
                return;
            }

            source.flip(true); // show button's real color

            // if user has selected first button
            if (firstPick == NO_PICK) {
                firstPick = source.getNumber(); // set first button pick field
            } else {
                // else user has selected 2nd button
                secondPick = source.getNumber();

                // check if the two buttons hold the same color
                Color c1 = buttonList.get(firstPick).getColor();
                Color c2 = buttonList.get(secondPick).getColor();
                if (c1.equals(c2)) {
                    // matching picks, then disable both buttons
                    buttonList.get(firstPick).setPairMatched(true);
                    buttonList.get(secondPick).setPairMatched(true);
                    // reset these variables
                    firstPick = NO_PICK;
                    secondPick = NO_PICK;
                    // check that the game isn't over
                    checkForWin();
                } else {
                    // start timer to display buttons for period of time, then
                    // flip back
                    listenerEnabled = false; // disable all button's action
                                             // listeners
                    new Timer(COLOR_DISPLAY_DELAY, e2 -> {
                        // show background color for both buttons
                        buttonList.get(firstPick).flip(false);
                        buttonList.get(secondPick).flip(false);

                        // re-enable the action listener
                        listenerEnabled = true;
                        firstPick = NO_PICK;
                        secondPick = NO_PICK;
                        ((Timer) e2.getSource()).stop(); // non-repeating timer
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkForWin() {
        boolean win = true;
        for (ColorButton2 button : buttonList) {
            win &= button.isPairMatched();
        }
        if (win) {
            String message = "You've matched all the colors";
            String title = "Congratulations!";
            int messageType = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ColorTest.this, message, title, messageType);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ColorTest mainPanel = new ColorTest();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ColorButton2 extends JButton {
    // background color
    private static final Color BG_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private int number;
    // non-background color
    private Color color = null;
    // true if a pair has been found for this button
    private boolean pairMatched = false;

    public ColorButton2(int number, int width, int height) {
        this.number = number;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setBackground(BG_COLOR);
    }

    // reset back to initial conditions
    public void reset() {
        setPairMatched(false);
        setBackground(BG_COLOR);
    }

    // if true -- show real color, else show background color
    public void flip(boolean flip) {
        if (flip) {
            setBackground(color);
        } else {
            setBackground(BG_COLOR);
        }
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public boolean isPairMatched() {
        return pairMatched;
    }

    // if match is found, disable the button and set the field
    public void setPairMatched(boolean pairMatched) {
        setEnabled(!pairMatched);
        this.pairMatched = pairMatched;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to extend JButton :/

Comment: @Kappa123: why? Is that an assignment requirement?

Comment: And regardless, you can do that, but the concepts in the answer are the same

Comment: Yeah it's a requirement. The ColorButton is just a ColorButton class which has all of the properties etc for the game that i'm making and then i'll just make a certain amount of those objects and use them in the game

Comment: I tried out the second one and it seems to work, i.e. the one which involves shuffling the array. The only thing is, what could I do so that it only picks from 8 different colours for the random colour? I was also trying to do this using a different method (creating an array of colour objects, picking two random buttons, assigning each pair a colour) so some of that may be useful.

Comment: @Kappa123: the code posted already does that -- creates 8 separate colors, but duplicates them and puts them into an ArrayList. But really you should be working out these details on your own. Come here for a specific question (which has already been answered), and then work on the details on your own. Not trying to be mean or cynical, but you look to be almost asking us to finish your homework for you which is not what this site is for.

Comment: In the code you posted which uses an array, which bit creates the 8 separate colours? I didn't really see it so I tried doing ``Color color = new Color(rand.nextInt(8)`` however this caused all of my squares to become black when clicked. I've updated my original post with the edited version of that that I got.

Comment: @Kappa123: `for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS / 2; i++) {` loops 8 times (if ROWS and COLS both are 4 -- do the math). So yes, the code creates 8 colors and adds them to the colorList twice. If you need further help you need to create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: @Kappa123: note that I don't think that this `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arrayButtons));` is doing what you think it is doing as I don't think that it's changing the array itself. Also, please comment back if/when you do create and post a [mcve] as I'd like to see and test it.

Comment: @Kappa123: mea culpa, it looks like your shuffle *does* work. Please pardon my error. I have tested this with an array of String and was surprised at the result.

Comment: It's fine! Glad to hear I did something correct at least :)

Comment: @Kappa123 -- for example